# Python. Вычислить лайфтайм по месяцам

Tags: python, datetime

Есть таблица вида

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a','2021-03-01','2021-11-01'], ['b','2021-03-01','2021-11-01'],
                   ['c','2021-03-01','2021-05-01'], ['d','2022-01-01','2022-01-01'],
                   ['e','2022-04-01','2022-06-01']], columns=['id','min_dt', 'max_dt'])
```

Необходимо добавить столбец, вычислив лайфтайм в месяцах. При простом вычитании получается интервал в количество дней, можно ли его преобразовать в количество месяцев?

Comment: Необходимо - сделайте. Хотя бы попытайтесь.

Comment: Да я могу сделать, большим количеством строк кода, разложив каждую дату на год и месяц, а потом произведя вычисления по столбцам.

А при простом вычитании получается интервал в количество дней.

мне интересно можно ли как-то его преобразовать в количество месяцев.

Comment: Ну можно в принципе разделить это количество дней на 30 и округлить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

был какой-то похожий вопрос сегодня уже...

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['a','2021-03-01','2021-11-01'], ['b','2021-03-01','2021-11-01'],
                   ['c','2021-03-01','2021-05-01'], ['d','2022-01-01','2022-01-01'],
                   ['e','2022-04-01','2022-06-01']], columns=['id','min_dt', 'max_dt'])
df["min_dt"] = pd.to_datetime(df["min_dt"])
df["max_dt"] = pd.to_datetime(df["max_dt"])
res = (df["max_dt"]-df["min_dt"]).astype("timedelta64[M]")
```

res:

```
0    8.0
1    8.0
2    2.0
3    0.0
4    2.0
```